# How to remove class after delay on submit button?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have put a delay on a submit button and add a class which gives the button a grey color.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttonDelay').click(function() {
        var delay =  $(this);
        delay.addClass('inactive');
        delay.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            delay.prop('disabled', false);
        }, 8000).removeClass('inactive');                      
    });
});
```

Now I like to remove the class 'inactive' so the button gets his original color back. But above code doesn't work. Anybody any ideas?

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/wPaUv/9/

Cheers,
Kessi

Answer (score 4):

`removeClass` is a jQuery method, you cannot chain that with `setTimeout` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttonDelay').click(function() {
        var delay =  $(this);
        delay.prop('disabled', true).addClass('inactive')
        setTimeout(function() {
            delay.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('inactive');
        }, 8000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yphKm/

Comment: This is true; the `[disabled]` selector in CSS could also be used.

Comment: @Kessi You are welcome, as primvdb suggests you can also use CSS `:disabled` selector http://jsfiddle.net/C4YNh/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#buttonDelay').click(function() {
    var delay =  $(this);
    delay.addClass('inactive');
    delay.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        delay.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('inactive');
    }, 8000);                      
});
});
```

You've just added the ​removeClass part to the wrong line.